# Android: What type of worker thread to implement for this scenario?

Tags: android, multithreading

I have an activity that needs to create a long-running worker thread.  This worker thread needs to respond to user input while it is running.  For example, I need to create a thread called 'ConstructionWorker', but I want to send it a commands like 'EatLunch' or 'WorkFaster' based on buttons in the UI.  The worker thread will then update the parent thread with progress.

I have implemented part of this using AsyncTask, but I don't see a way to create 'WorkSlower' or 'WorkFaster' functions that I can then call from the UI thread.

What type of threading technique should I use for this?  I'm guessing AsyncTask is not the way to tackle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use HandlerThread instead of AsyncTask,

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
private HandlerThread mBackgroundThread;
private Handler mBackgroundHandler;

private static final int BACKGROUND_TASK_WORK_SLOWER = 0;
private static final int BACKGROUND_TASK_WORK_FASTER = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_content);

    Button btnWorkSlower = (Button) findViewById(R.id.work_slower);
    btnWorkSlower.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button btnFaster = (Button) findViewById(R.id.work_faster);
    btnFaster.setOnClickListener(this);

    mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("ConstructionWorker",
            Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
    mBackgroundThread.start();
    mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundThread.getLooper()) {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            performBackgroundTask(msg.what, msg.obj);
        }
    };
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.work_slower:
        scheduleBackgroundTask(BACKGROUND_TASK_WORK_SLOWER);
        break;
    case R.id.work_faster:
        scheduleBackgroundTask(BACKGROUND_TASK_WORK_FASTER);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

protected void scheduleBackgroundTask(int task) {
    mBackgroundHandler.sendEmptyMessage(task);
}

protected void performBackgroundTask(int task, Object arg) {
    switch (task) {
    case BACKGROUND_TASK_WORK_SLOWER: {
        // work slower here
        break;
    }
    case BACKGROUND_TASK_WORK_FASTER: {
        // work faster here
        break;
    }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This looks good.  Question -- how would the Construction worker thread communicate progress?

Answer (score 0):

Use an asynctask for the background thread.

Then create a message queue. As you'll be doing cross thread synchronization, make sure you use synchronize() around shared data structures such as the queue itself when pushing and popping messages.

Have your UI thread post messages into the queue, and have your asynctask loop, poll the queue for messages.